# In Fortran, is it possible to pass a NULL argument to an MPIO subroutine?

Tags: fortran, mpi

In the example 4.23 (p.137) of the MPI 3.1 standard, some NULL arguments are passed to MPI_Gatherv:

```
MPI_Gatherv(lbuf, position, MPI_PACKED, NULL,
            NULL, NULL, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL, root, comm);
```

Some arguments may be null because they are only significant at the root process. But the example is in C. Is there a way to do the same in Fortran?

Comment: The MPI 3.1 standard can be found at http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf

Comment: It's not the same but in Fortran I do this by allocating the relevant arrays to zero size on the processes where they are not needed. If this answers your question I can turn this into a proper answer.

Comment: You may not pass unallocated allocatable or unassociated pointer to any such simple procedure, no matter if MPI or not, so Ian is correct. Sometimes it may not crash (I had such a silent bug for a long time in my code) but it is certainly not allowed. A procedure would have to be specially designed to allow pointer or allocatable arguments to allow NULL and similar.

Comment: @IanBush I'm also currently using zero size arrays, but I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it, as this is the case in C.

Comment: Yes, there is. Use the modern Fortran bindings from MPI 3 (`use mpi_f2008`).

Comment: Try C_null_ptr of iso_c_binding

Comment: Just to say I don't think Allocate( array( 1:Merge( upper_bound, 0, rank == 0 ) ) leads to anything more or less elegant than C - especially when it's considered that the example referred to burns in the maximum number of processes as 64. It's just different, when your writing Fortran write Fortran, not C.